# Is there a way to import data from word to R

Tags: r, excel, import, ms-word, vba

Our lab gives EDS results as a word file like the one below.[image: Sample EDS Result]

My usual process is to copy the table to an excel sheet like [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038461/moving-data-from-ms-word-to-ms-excel) however I've got more than 50 results and would like to speed things up. There is a macro for getting tables from Word to Excel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465212/macro-to-export-ms-word-tables-to-excel-sheets). It is faster than copy paste but it doesn't cycle through all files in a folder.

Is there a way to get data off of Word to R?